# How to make forloops run only through unique values in Django Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

**Intro:** I have a model called `event` which has a ForeignKey `post`. The way it works is: ***Example*** A user creates a Post called "Solar Eclipse". Any number of users can create a event based on that post. So if someone goes on that post detail page. It has a button called `See all Events` They can see all people who are hosting Solar Eclipse Event. Say there are 5 posts(on different topics like skiing, hiking etc) and 3 of them have 10 events each. 2 posts have no events. On my Homepage I have a section that says Events. In the events section of homepage I want to show 3 posts which have events not 30 events How do I do that. Such that I don't hit the DataBase too many times

Below are the **views.py**

```
class EventView(ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'home.html'    
    context_object_name = 'all_events' 

    def get_queryset(self): 
        for post in Post.objects.all():
             return post.event_post.all() #event_post is a related_name of post see models below

#This is incorrect it shows the post 30 times. 10 times for each event. I want to see only 3 posts. They can see the events when they click to open the post
```

How can I achieve this:

my **event models.py** are

```
class Event(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='host')
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='event_post')
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
        stock = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(15)])
        initial_stock = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(15)], default=1)
        date = models.DateField()
        time_from = models.TimeField()
        time_to = models.TimeField()
        available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        note = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

my **post models.py** are

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    message_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modified @OhGreatOne's code a bit to match my needs

```
for post in Post.objects.all():
    if post.event_post.exists():
        print.post.title:
```

Can't believe it was so simple

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do `Post.objects.all()` then display the details of that post on your template. Then when you click on one. Then you can pass `selected_post.event_post_set.all()`. If this doesn't answer your question, let me know.

Edit: This will work, i think you are confused a little maybe? Just because your link says events, does not mean you have to use that model. Yeah you should call this view like `PostView`use a model of `Post` and return that. This will return your 3 posts. Then when you click on one, you pass that post pk to your new `EventView` which will do something like...

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=passed_in_post_pk)
...
return post.event_post_set.all()
```

To check if post has at least an event in it. You can take some queryset and slap a `.exists()` on the end, and do an `if` statement.

```
post_events_exist = post.event_post_set.all().exists()
if post_events_exist:
    # there is at least 1 event in the query set.
```

**Full Example somewhat Pseudo Code:**

views.py

```
# Rename EventView --> PostView
# Inside of your now PostView
# All we need to do is return all your instances of Post
# and go to your post_template.html (shows the posts, you call it events)
return Post.objects.all()

# Inside of a new view called EventView
# We can get to this view by clicking one of the posts above.
# This assumes we send a parameter through url in template.
# This will send user to event_template.html (shows all events for that post)
post = Post.objects.get(pk=passed_in_post_pk)
return post.post_event_set.all()
```

post_template.html

```
<!-- assuming all_posts = Post.objects.all() -->
{% for post in all_posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    <a href="{{ url_that_links_to_event_view post.pk }}">Info</a>
    <!-- this will send post.pk as a parameter to that view (so long as your accept a parameter in your urls.py for this link -->
{% endfor %}
```

event_template.html

```
{% for event in all_events %}
    {{ event.price }}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't work with Class Based Views because I think they suck, but this pseudo code should be good enough for you to implement it. I provided the syntax of exactly what you need with filler values/variable.

Comment: Just a small issue with that is, It is not mandatory for posts to have events to them. Example if there is a post on skiing, In the summer there would be no events to that post. I only want to show posts that have events associated with them, I have updated the question according too. The second part of your answer is awesome `selected_post.events.all()` is a real good code thanks for that

Comment: Updated my answer to answer your question. Btw I also edited the piece of code you said was awesome. I believe it should be `selected_post.event_set.all()` so I apologize if it didn't work before.

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around `Post.objects.get(pk=passed_in_post_pk)`  The only way I could was to send it is through the forloop of ` for post in Post.objects.all():` also then when I use `post.event_set.all()`  I get a error saying  `AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'event_set'`

Comment: Didn't realize you set a related name. I fixed all my code above and gave you a full example of what you should do. `post.event_post_set.all()` will work correctly.